# Can't find RecyclerView visible item position inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I get the first/ last completely visible item in a recyclerview if it is inside a NestedScrollView and the recycler has `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` for smooth scrolling with other views above the RecyclerView.

All these functions

`int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();`

either return the first/last item created in the recyclerView.

I want to find the current visible item because I want to make the RecyclerView scroll infinitely and I should fetch data if only a few items are left to scroll.

Thanks

Comment: I have same problem. But I can't find my anwser. :(

Comment: @BuiMinhDuc So actually there is no way we can achieve that. The best option is to do what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Also, getChildCount() always returns same as getItemCount().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I couldn't find any way in which two `RecyclerView` could be inside a `NestedScrollView` and still say which item is visible on the screen.

So my solution was to remove the `NestedScrollView` and make the Vertical RecycelerView the main view in the page and add the Horizontal `RecyclerView` as the first item of on Vertical Recycler. As I only wanted to know the position for the Vertical Recycler, I can get that now by using any of the methods mentioned in the question.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48430598/4593755), the answer explain why these method not work.

Comment: There is a solution is that you should set height for RecyclerView view inside NestedScrollView

Answer (score 7):

You can add scroll listner on nestedscrollview and while scrolling check each item in recylerview that is placed inside the nestedScrollview that is visible or not.
Below is the example

```
  val scrollBounds = Rect()
  nestedScrollView?.getHitRect(scrollBounds)

  nestedScrollView?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
         override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val scrollBounds = Rect()
                if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.adapter != null
                            && recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount != null
                            && recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount!! > 0) {
                     for (i in 0 until recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount!!) {
                         var view = recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)?.itemView

                         if (view != null) {
                            if (view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                               if (!view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
                                            || scrollBounds.width() < view.getWidth()) {
                                        Logger.debugLog("WidgetScrolled", "BTN APPEAR PARCIALY")
                                    } else {
                                        Logger.debugLog("WidgetScrolled", "BTN APPEAR FULLY!!!")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Logger.debugLog("WidgetScrolled", "No")
                                }
                    }
               }
          }
      }
  })
```

Comment: working great in nested recyclerview. Thanks a million.

Comment: I think `val scrollBounds = Rect()` just below `super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)` should be removed. Anyway, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

**I know its too late. But i got solution. (Java code)**

So my solution is instead of trying find the last visible item of RecyclerView. I added OnScrollChangeListener to NestedScrollView for detecting the last item.

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    if (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                            if (scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
                                //code to fetch more data for endless scrolling
                              
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

When we add RecylerView in a NestedScrollView, while scrolling the function findLastVisibleItemPosition always return the last item in the list.

So my solution is instead of trying find the last visible item of RecyclerView. I added OnScrollChangeListener to NestedScrollView for detecting the last item.

```
scvHome.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
            val isLoadingMore = homeViewModel.isLoadingMoreProduct.value ?: false
            if (!isLoadingMore) {
                v?.let {
                    val currentHeight = (v?.getChildAt(0).measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight)
                    if (scrollY == currentHeight && hasMoreProduct()) {
                        homeViewModel.loadMoreProduct()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```