# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView does not give correct visible item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` and I'm trying to get the position of the last visible list item during scroll events using. The following code allows me to reliably detect scroll events:

```
val recyclerView = nestedScrollView.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView

nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { v: NestedScrollView?, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->
    val layoutManager = recyclerView?.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager
    val lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager?.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
}
```

The problem however is that here `lastVisiblePosition` always ends up being the last item in the list whether this is actually on scree or not. Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: set recylcerview.setnestedscrolllingenabled(false);

Comment: I did that. Makes no difference.

Comment: What is the height of your recyclerview?

Comment: I tried both wrap_content and match_parent. First visible item is always the first list item and last is always the last item.

Answer (score 15):

If you put a `RecyclerView` inside a scrollable container—a `NestedScrollView` in your case—it will basically become a fancy `LinearLayout`, inflating and showing all the items at once. You get the first and last item as the first and last one visible because—to the RecyclerView—they are. All the items got inflated and added, so all of them are "visible on screen" inside the scrollable view.

The easy solution would be to just not nest the RecyclerView inside the NestedScrollView. A RecyclerView can scroll already, so you could just put whatever header or footer you need inside the RecyclerView as well. Nesting scrollable views always has drawbacks and you should try to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: So, there is no way to stop recyclerview from inflating all items at a time when it is inside nestedscrollview?

Comment: what if we want to implement collapsing app bar @David

Comment: @ParthAnjaria then you use a CoordinatorLayout with the AppBarLayout & RecyclerView. There should be plenty of examples online

Comment: what if I want to add swipe to refresh with recyclerview? @DavidMedenjak

Comment: @NevilGhelani SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't interfere with RVs recycling

Comment: @DavidMedenjak You are right but I want to make an app that can refresh recycler view on swipe. Is there any way to do?

Comment: @NevilGhelani I'm not sure what you are asking. Just put RV into a SwipeRefreshLayout? `<SwipeRefreshLayout><RecyclerView/></SwipeRefreshLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot of sites and can not find a solution for using findLastVisibleItemPosition method. I used another solution and answered it in there:
[Can't find RecyclerView visible item position inside NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370430/cant-find-recyclerview-visible-item-position-inside-nestedscrollview/67702550#67702550)